# How to make 3 column layout layout in yii 2

Tags: yii, yii2

In yii1 i was able to create additional layouts like column1, column2 on one page. The old method in yii 1 doesnt work.

how am i able to achieve this with yii2? say the page is divided into 3 columns one showing in, out and missed.

**www\center\protected\views\layout\column1.php**

```
<?php /* @var $this Controller */ ?>
<?php $this->beginContent('//layouts/main'); ?>
<div id="content">
    <?php echo $content; ?>
</div><!-- content -->
<?php $this->endContent(); ?>
```

**www\center\protected\views\layout\column2.php**

```
<?php /* @var $this Controller */ ?>
<?php $this->beginContent('//layouts/main'); ?>
<div class="span-19">
    <div id="content">
        <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div><!-- content -->
</div>
<div class="span-5 last">
    <div id="sidebar">
    <?php
        $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.CPortlet', array(
            'title'=>'Operations',
        ));
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
            'items'=>$this->menu,
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'operations'),
        ));
        $this->endWidget();
    ?>
    </div><!-- sidebar -->
</div>
<?php $this->endContent(); ?>
```

How can it be achieved in Yii 2.0 ?

Comment: you could use layouts  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#layouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use layout in yii2 by doing this:

1) set your view in layout at @app/views/layouts or if you in module in moduleBasePath - views/layouts

2)

```
<?php
    use yii\helpers\Html;

    /* @var $this yii\web\View */
    /* @var $content string */
    ?>
    <?php $this->beginPage() ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
        <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
        <?php $this->head() ?>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php $this->beginBody() ?>
        <header>My Company</header>
        <div class="span-19">
            <?= $content ?>
        </div>
        <div class="span-5 last">
            // Your code
        </div>
        <footer>&copy; 2014 by My Company</footer>
    <?php $this->endBody() ?>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

3) You can access layout by adding

```
public $layout = 'newLayout';
```

In Your controller, or you can use it specific action like

```
$this->layout = 'newLayout';
```

Good luck